# Deshabilitar scroll horizontal; pero permitir el vertical

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Estoy tratando de desactivar el scroll horizontal en un sitio web; pero sin afectar al vertical.

Tengo un script que funciona como un control deslizante deslizando el "cuerpo" de la página hacia la izquierda y revelando más contenidos. Sin embargo, esto crea un espacio vacío adicional a la derecha.

Tengo que desactivar el desplazamiento horizontal para que los usuarios no vean este espacio vacío. He probado lo siguiente; pero deshabilita tanto el desplazamiento horizontal como el vertical:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
     window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

He probado con el estilo `overflow-x:hidden` pero eso no funciona cuando el ancho del `body` es dinámico y no estático.

#### Pregunta:

¿Hay alguna forma de modificar mi script para deshabilitar el scroll horizontal y mantener el vertical en funcionamiento?

---

**Pregunta original:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/22678482/4359029

Comment: No se, pero creo que la pregunta que colocas al final de tu pregunta, como que no tiene que ver con la pregunta hecha acá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estabas cerca de conseguirlo; necesitas obtener el `document` —o `window`— y enlazarlo con el scroll, después puedes comprobar si el scroll horizontal es actualizado a un valor **mayor de 0** y, de ser así, reasignarle el valor **0**

El siguiente código funciona bien:

```js
$(function() {
  var $body = $(document);
  $body.bind('scroll', function() {
    // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
    if ($body.scrollLeft() !== 0) {
      $body.scrollLeft(0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 150%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis,
sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus
elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum.
Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit
vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec
sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in
dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet
nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras
id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci.
Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere
vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer
vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin
urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum
primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero.
```

Si quieres desactivar el scroll horizontal de un elemento (*como un `div`, por ejemplo*) necesitas reemplazar `$(document)` por `$("#IDElemento")`

---

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/tomloprod/zx1bvdf5/

---

> **NOTA:**
>
> El código superior evitará utilizar el scroll horizontal, además, puedes usar el siguiente estilo CSS: `overflow-x:hidden` para ocultar el scroll horizontal.
>
> **Y será como si no existiera ningún scroll horizontal**

---

**Mi respuesta original:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/29431155/4359029

Answer (score 11):

Otra posible solución a este problema puede ser via Css, y es usando `overflow-x: hidden;`

Por ejemplo lo colocas en tu body de esta forma:

```
body{
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Y automaticamente ocultara todo scroll x (Horizontal) que este en el body.

Te dejo un ejemplo en vivo, que a mi parecer se ve mas limpio.

```css
body{    
   width:150%;
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc, quis gravida magna mi a libero. Fusce vulputate eleifend sapien. Vestibulum purus quam, scelerisque ut, mollis sed, nonummy id, metus. Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Cras ultricies mi eu turpis hendrerit fringilla. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In ac dui quis mi consectetuer lacinia. Nam pretium turpis et arcu. Duis arcu tortor, suscipit eget, imperdiet nec, imperdiet iaculis, ipsum. Sed aliquam ultrices mauris. Integer ante arcu, accumsan a, consectetuer eget, posuere ut, mauris. Praesent adipiscing. Phasellus ullamcorper ipsum rutrum nunc. Nunc nonummy metus. Vestibulum volutpat pretium libero. Cras id dui. Aenean ut eros et nisl sagittis vestibulum. Nullam nulla eros, ultricies sit amet, nonummy id, imperdiet feugiat, pede. Sed lectus. Donec mollis hendrerit risus. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam imperdiet imperdiet orci. Nunc nec neque. Phasellus leo dolor, tempus non, auctor et, hendrerit quis, nisi. Curabitur ligula sapien, tincidunt non, euismod vitae, posuere imperdiet, leo. Maecenas malesuada. Praesent congue erat at massa. Sed cursus turpis vitae tortor. Donec posuere vulputate arcu. Phasellus accumsan cursus velit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed aliquam, nisi quis porttitor congue, elit erat euismod orci, ac placerat dolor lectus quis orci. Phasellus consectetuer vestibulum elit. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Vestibulum fringilla pede sit amet augue. In turpis. Pellentesque posuere. Praesent turpis. Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc, eu sollicitudin urna dolor sagittis lacus. Donec elit libero, sodales nec, volutpat a, suscipit non, turpis. Nullam sagittis. Suspendisse pulvinar, augue ac venenatis condimentum, sem libero volutpat nibh, nec pellentesque velit pede quis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce id purus. Ut varius tincidunt libero.
```

[Demo en jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pL1oL611/)

Comment: Esta solución es mas limpia y tiene mejor performance

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo en que sea una solución;  ya que esto sólo **oculta** el scroll horizontal, cuando lo que se necesita es **deshabilitarlo**. Aunque el scroll no sea visible, sigue siendo funcional (como por ejemplo, en pantallas táctiles o al seleccionar texto).

Comment: @tomloprod Bueno la verdad esta 1000% comprobado, que si puedes hacer algo por `css` que por `javascript`, es mejor hacerlo por la primera vía. Con respecto al punto que mencionas, yo he usado esto en app moviles con phonegap y me ha funcionado perfectamente, algo haz estado haciendo mal. Adiconalmente no esta colocado Android en la pregunta original y menos acá, así que tu argumento no es del todo valido.

Comment: No me he referido a dispositivos móviles, @WilfredoP, sino a pantallas táctiles. Y mantengo mi opinión de que esto no es una solución; pues sólo **oculta** el scroll horizontal. No lo **desactiva**, que es la pregunta en cuestión. 

Es más, en mi respuesta también hablo de la propiedad CSS que mencionas; pero indico que **sólo** ocultará el scroll, por lo que, al menos en este caso, podría usarse conjuntamente con la solución JS.

Comment: @tomloprod Bueh... es una solución alternativa, no caeré si esta buena o esta mal, incluso en el post original otra persona la da como alternativa y yo la escribí sin mirar ese post. Solo mide el performance de los que estas haciendo y veras, y ojo yo no vote negativa tu pregunta, el que lo hizo sabe de que hablo.

Comment: @WilfredoP La verdad es que no me planteé en ningún momento que hayas votado negativa mi pregunta, en cuanto a eso no te preocupes :)

Con respecto a nuestro debate, la verdad es que sigo manteniendo mi opinión, me baso principalmente en lo siguiente: utilizando únicamente el estilo CSS que tú mencionas, el scroll sigue activo, no se desactiva. Y esto puede ser fácilmente comprobado mediante: una pantalla táctil, el teclado y el ratón.

Si te apetece, podemos discutirlo en el chat, para no llenar esto de comentarios; y quiero que quede claro, que, al menos para mi, es un debate amistoso. :)